# Why does removing this dropdown menu break this app?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, drop-down-menu

This is not my code, but I'm working with an application that contains two activities and a dropdown menu. You can navigate between the two activities via the dropdown. My goal is to remove one of the activities and the dropdown menu. What I have accomplished is simply removing the activity from the dropdown menu so that it defaults to the other, so now I need to remove the dropdown menu. However, since the activity that is displayed is defined by the dropdown, if I try to remove the dropdown it will just draw a blank page displaying only the action bar. Anyone have a possible solution judging from this code?

```html
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
  ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
 
 protected final String LOG = ".MainActivity";
 
 /**
  * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
  * current dropdown position.
  */
 private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
  final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
  actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
  actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
  actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
  actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

  // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
  actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
  // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBarThemedContextCompat(),
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
      android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
        //getString(R.string.title_section_recent),
        getString(R.string.title_section_all), }), this);
  
  /**if(!getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("disclaimer_accepted", false)) {
   DialogFragment dialog = new DisclaimerDialogFragment();
   dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DisclaimerDialogFragment");
  }**/
 }

 /**
  * Backward-compatible version of {@link ActionBar#getThemedContext()} that
  * simply returns the {@link android.app.Activity} if
  * <code>getThemedContext</code> is unavailable.
  */
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
 private Context getActionBarThemedContextCompat() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
   return getActionBar().getThemedContext();
  } else {
   return this;
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Restore the previously serialized current dropdown position.
  if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
   getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
     savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
  }
 }
 
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
 }
 
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.action_view_source:
   Intent i2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i2.setData(Uri.parse(this.getString(R.string.url_source)));
   this.startActivity(i2);
   return true;

  case R.id.action_view_translation:
   Intent i3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i3.setData(Uri.parse(this.getString(R.string.url_translation)));
   this.startActivity(i3);
   return true;
   
  case R.id.action_view_bugs:
   Intent i4 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i4.setData(Uri.parse(this.getString(R.string.url_bugs)));
   this.startActivity(i4);
   return true;
   
  default:
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
 }


 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  // Serialize the current dropdown position.
  outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
    .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
  // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
  // container view.

  Fragment fragment = null;
  switch(position) {
  case 0:
   fragment = new AllTasksListFragment();
   break;
  case 1:
   //fragment = new RecentTaskListFragment();
   break;
  }

  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
  return true;
 }
}
```

```html
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all your activity does is show a fragment.  And the fragment is selected during onNavigationItemSelected.  If that isn't called, then you never set a default fragment.  So in your onCreate, add a transaction to add the fragment you want to keep.  Then you can kill the dropdown.